# как поставить курсор в TextBox при загрузке страницы

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, textbox, focus

У меня есть веб-форма, при загрузке которой, мне необходимо поставить курсор в textBox, для дальнейших действий. Суть моей проблемы:При загрузке страницы мне необходимо, чтобы курсор стоял в текстбоксе для того, чтобы на него с планшета приходила строка. обычным `TextBox.Focus()` это не решается.Подкиньте варианты, пожалуйста

Comment: `обычным TextBox.Focus() это не решается` какие проблемы с этим?

Comment: пробовали [Page.SetFocus(TextBox)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.page.setfocus?view=netframework-4.8)?

Comment: Page.SetFocus(TextBox) - помогло, спасибо!

Comment: А если я помещаю после какого-то действия фокус, должно также работать?

Comment: ещё пара таких вопросов от вас и меня забанят за накрутку :)

Comment: Я не знаю, что будет если вы что то сделаете, я с WebForms работал в последний раз в 2012, просто пробуйте

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте [`Page.SetFocus`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.page.setfocus?view=netframework-4.8)

```
 Page.SetFocus(TextBox);
```